# Make Logback include the "T" between date and time in its "%date" format for strict ISO 8601 compliance

Tags: java, logback

By default, the [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) encoder uses a [date format](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#date) similar to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. But it lacks the "T" in the middle between the date and time portions. The `T` makes for easier parsing, and is required by the standard (unless private parties agree otherwise).

Is there some trick to **get Logback to include the `T`**?

This…

```
2006-10-20T14:06:49,812
```

instead of this…

```
2006-10-20 14:06:49,812
```

I suppose I could re-create the entire format while adding a "T", but I wonder if there is some simpler way.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Bug Report

There's a bug report about this on [Logback's JIRA page](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-262?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel). There hasn't been much development since `24/Feb/10 3:57 PM`. I've just voted to attract attention. You should too.

I would provide my own date format that matches [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)'s.

## Insert "T"

This should do the trick:

```
<pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
</pattern>
```

The `""` are needed to make the `,` work as described in the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html).

That `<pattern>` element belongs in your Logback configuration setting. Here is an example `logback.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Strangely, Logback lacks a built-in formatter for ISO 8601. So, roll our own.  -->
            <Pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.example" level="TRACE"/>


    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

## Time Zone

To be more fully ISO 8601 compliant, and for more helpful logging, you should include a time zone.

EDIT (Michael-O, 2014-06-15): That is *not* true, timezone is absolute optional.

To include a time zone, pass a second argument ([see doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#date)) to the `%date`. Pass the [proper name of a time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Avoid the three or four letter time zone codes such as "EST" as they are neither unique nor standardized. For example, pass `Australia/Perth`. Generally for logging we want [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (GMT) time, meaning without any offset. In that case, pass `UTC`.

You can display the time zone offset as number of hours and minutes as part of the date-time in the log. Append an `X` to display the time zone offset as part of the date time value.

This…

```
%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", UTC}
```

…produces…

```
2014-04-16T09:59:24,009Z
```

The `XXX` works in Java 7 and 8. In earlier versions of Java, you may be able to use a `Z` in the format definition to generate an offset number that lacks a colon.